# Insert multiple rows from select result

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, bulkinsert

For a database fix I have to perform I need to do an insert for every **ID** this query results;

```
SELECT Id FROM role WHERE id != 99 AND Id NOT IN (SELECT RoleId FROM permissionaction WHERE PermissionId = 19);
```

So it results some ID's which have to be added with this query.

```
  INSERT INTO permissionaction (AccessLevel, PermissionId, ControllerActionId, Active, CreatedOn, ModifiedOn, CreatedById, ModifiedById, RoleId) VALUES (1, 19, 1, 1, Now(), Now(), 1, 1, *******ID HERE******);
```

I know it can be done with using mysql cursors but it's not a possibility here. Is there a way to add all of the resulting ID's in one query?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`INSERT...SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO permissionaction (AccessLevel, PermissionId, ControllerActionId, Active, CreatedOn, ModifiedOn, CreatedById, ModifiedById, RoleId)
SELECT 1, 19, 1, 1, Now(), Now(), 1, 1, Id
FROM role
WHERE id != 99
AND Id NOT IN (SELECT RoleId FROM permissionaction WHERE PermissionId = 19);
```

With `INSERT...SELECT` you can add values to the table `permissionaction` for each returned row of the `SELECT` query.

Comment: Turned out quite easy. Thank you, it works perfectly.